# actTakePicture in Sony HDR-AS50 and PostviewImageSize

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

When taking a picture with `actTakePicture` for the ActionCam Sony HDR-AS50 using the API of the camera, the posted jpeg returns a `2M` size jpeg. How can the full `Original` picture can be retrieved through WiFi?

The `setPostviewImageSize` seems not to be available.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuantely the original picture cannot be retrieved using the API since as you noted the setPostviewImageSize API is not supported on that camera.